# How to save an intent's data

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following situation: I need to save data from an Intent's `putExtra` call into another `Activity`. I am able to display the `putExtra` data, however I cannot save it. I am using `startActivity` to start the activity that I need to save the data in. I am attempting to store it by adding the data to an `ArrayList`, however whenever I change Activities the data is lost. Also it only stores the last value. How can I store the sent data in the second `Activity`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"I cannot save it"_? Can you retrieve that data in your destination activity?

Comment: @Chopin Yes I can retrieve the data in the destination activity. However, whenever I switch back to the activity that sent the data, I lose the data. Its as if the receiving application gets re-created every time I switch over to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in the Application Context as described here:

[Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)